# Centered section number without section name

Tags: sectioning, article

How to achieve the stated in the title with the symbol **§** followed by the section number without the section name. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a not-too-unusual document class, you can achieve your typesetting objective by loading the `sectsty` package, issuing the `\sectionfont` directive, and redefining `\thesection`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\S\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
abc
\hrule
\section{}
\hrule
\bigskip
\section{}
\hrule
def
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have space between § and the section number ?  And how can I call the section number followed by § ?

Comment: @Fib1123 - On your first question: Just replace `{\S\arabic{section}}` with `{\S\ \arabic{section}}, for an interword space in the code shown above, or `{\S\quad \arabic{section}}` for a "quad" of space. On your second question: do try `{\arabic{section} \S}`.